# I want to bring css for select option. how to write for this image, sample output like this

Tags: css

```
  <select name="productsize">
    <option value="s">s</option>
    <option value="m">m</option>
    </select>
```

How to write css for select option, sample image attached. I have given only select option code from this we want to write the css property. I want to know what are the property we want to use.

[image: How to write css for select option, sample image attached]

Comment: should use radio buttons rather than a select.

Comment: no.this is shopping cart site, so we need only select option.

Comment: so what if it's eccomerce? if you want it to look like your image, you should be using radio, not a select. there's no functional difference between the 2, its just better for styling the way you want.

Comment: understood, but select option means it's ok, my sample link from client, boot the page in server, you got what i trying to do  http://chlorophile.co.in/index.php/collection/men/graphic-tees/men-s-save-the-forest.html

Comment: @hazonko did u complete.

Comment: please send me radio button code. let us see

Comment: @hazonko are u there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try this:

```
<style>
.productsize li{
float: left;
padding: 13px;
border: 1px black solid;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 20px;
border-radius: 21px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.productsize{
list-style-type:none;
}
.active{
background-color:grey;
}
</style>
<ul name="productsize" class="productsize">
<li value="s" >s</li>
<li value="m" >m</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script>
$("ul li").on('click',function(){
$('ul li').removeClass('active');
$(this).toggleClass("active");
});
</script>
```

Comment: hi i tried in individual page. it comes only  s, m with  light circle. have u executed .  because by selection value have to pass to server sideif possible connect with fiddle. let us finish this.

Comment: Thanks lot , I have another question ? using ul name product size, I will get the list value ? will I get the list value in this way also?